# Unique filter which ignores multiple values

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

So this is the formula I have for filter;

```
=unique(filter('Equipment Tracking'!D:D,'Equipment Tracking'!D:D<>""))
```

which shows me all the things I need and ignores all blank cells, however, I just need a way of ignoring other certain values in this list as well.

For example, my list currently looks like

[image: this]

and I need to ignore values like `broken` and `missing`

Comment: "ignoring other certain values in this list as well" - like for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply ad 2nd, 3rd, n-th parameter to the `FILTER` fx like:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('Equipment Tracking'!D:D, 'Equipment Tracking'!D:D<>"",
                                         'Equipment Tracking'!D:D<>"moon"))
```

also you can use regex if you have a larger list to ignore:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('Equipment Tracking'!D:D, 'Equipment Tracking'!D:D<>"",
                              REGEXMATCH('Equipment Tracking'!D:D, "[^moon|sun|mars]")))
```